# Override class not working on linux server in magento2?

Tags: magento2, overrides

I want to override Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Adapter class 
 i have set in di.xml

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0"?>
>    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
>    <preference for="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Adapter" type="Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Adapter" />
>    </config>
> ```

and my Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Adapter code is:

```
<?php

 namespace Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import;

  use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write;


 class Adapter extends \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Adapter
{
/**
 * Adapter factory. Checks for availability, loads and create instance of import adapter object.
 *
 * @param string $type Adapter type ('csv', 'xml' etc.)
 * @param Write $directory
 * @param string $source
 * @param mixed $options OPTIONAL Adapter constructor options
 *
 * @return AbstractSource
 *
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public static function factory($type, $directory, $source, $options = null)
{
    if (!is_string($type) || !$type) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('The adapter type must be a non-empty string.')
        );
    }
   // $adapterClass = 'Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Source\\' . ucfirst(strtolower($type));
    $adapterClass = 'Tatva\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Source\\' . ucfirst(strtolower($type));

    if (!class_exists($adapterClass)) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('\'%1\' file extension is not supported', $type)
        );
    }
    $adapter = new $adapterClass($source, $directory, $options);

    if (!$adapter instanceof AbstractSource) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            __('Adapter must be an instance of \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource')
        );
    }
    return $adapter;
}

/**
 * Create adapter instance for specified source file.
 *
 * @param string $source Source file path.
 * @param Write $directory
 * @param mixed $options OPTIONAL Adapter constructor options
 *
 * @return AbstractSource
 */
public static function findAdapterFor($source, $directory, $options = null)
{
    return self::factory(pathinfo($source, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $directory, $source, $options);
}
}
```

it's working on xampp server but not linux server.

I have flushed cache and setup upgrade and di compile command already run but still not working

Comment: have you checked that file executable for web server user?

Comment: @kunj sorry not following you.
Can you please tell me how to check?

Comment: Check that file access by the terminal using `ls -lath` command. you will see the file accessible user name, group and access limit like this `-rw-r--r--  1 kunj developer 3.1K Jul 16 15:05 composer.json`

Comment: yes it's giving result -rw-r--r-- 1

Comment: can you please check your directory name with lowcase and upercase??

Comment: @HoangHieu Have checked so many times.it's same.

Comment: yes let's say one file have access for 'test' user and second file have access for web server user 'admin' so scond file will run 'admin'  and first file will not.

Comment: @RutveeSojitra with Low and uper case ??

Comment: @HoangHieu yes , checked.

Comment: Check your config.php file make sure your Module enabled.

Comment: Yes it's on. already checked

Comment: Try to replace below code in di.xml, may be it will help:
<type name="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Adapter">
 <plugin name="AdapterPlug" type="Namespace\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\Adapter" />
</type>

Comment: then i have to modified all the code right?
means i have to make plugin right?

Comment: No, just need to update in di.xml file

Comment: @jmt then how AdapterPlug will work?